# Ignore parts of an equation with multiple variable in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8, wolfram-language

I want to use the linear version of a somewhat big equation which is outputted by my Mathematica code - For simplicity I will here use the example equation:

```
Test = 3 x + x y + 8 y
```

Now, I want to use only the first order term, so that for `x` that will be `3` and for `y` that will be 8. I have tried to get those using

```
Coefficient[Test, x]
Coefficient[Test, y]
```

However these give me for x:

```
3+y
```

and for y:

```
8+x
```

Is there anyway I can use Mathematica to ignore the terms that depend in both xy simultaneously?

Comment: Mathematica has its dedicated SE site: [mathematica.se] ,you may also ask questions there.